# Поиск через AJAX

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Как организовать серверную сторону(PHP,БД) для поиска пользователей(AJAX на keydown), как в Гугле, ВК, Твиттере и т.п.

Есть таблица users

```
 1  id        int(11)            A_I 
 2  log_name varchar(40)                      
 3  name    varchar(32)             
 4  surname varchar(32)                  
 5  pass    varchar(50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё довольно просто.
На каждый keydown отправляете запрос к PHP-скрипту, а он обращается к БД и ищет в ней нужные совпадения, после чего получаете результаты и выводите их там где нужно.

Если хотите более подробный ответ - опишите с чем именно у вас проблемы.

Comment: а  запрос должен выглядеть как то так? с LIKE

          SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '...%' OR LIKE surname = '...%'

Comment: Да, примерно так.